# How can I break two Splunk logs in same row?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I am trying to break two logs which are logged in the same row because of which the next log is not getting published in the result while extracting, while it is showing in the event log.

```
02:09:50.296 64785434 [http-bio-8085-exec-156] INFO  c.i.p.w.r.s.AdjustmentServiceImpl - publicRequest: ,AccountID=123147309786219,ProductName="Product Online",ProductFlavor="ENHANCED",EventType=Usage,AdjustmentType=event,AdjustmentInputType=Amount,BillDate=2018-07-09,AdjustmentReason="Chargeback Event Adjustment",,SOAP Request:,AccountPOID="0.0.0.1 /account 324245253535",EventPOID="0.0.0.1 /event/activity/usage/payroll_per_employee 311258547968527414",AdjustmentAmount=1,AdjustmentPercentage=,Currency=GBP,Bill-ItemNo=23627727,1,AdjustmentDate=2018-07-14T04:00-07:00,IS_DEBIT_OR_CREDIT=CREDIT,TaxTreatment="Included Taxes in this adjustment",,SOAP Response:HttpStatus=200,,
02:09:50.826 64785964 [http-bio-8085-exec-156] INFO  c.i.p.w.r.s.AdjustmentServiceImpl - publicRequest: ,AccountID=123147309786219,ProductName="Product Online",ProductFlavor="ENHANCED",EventType=Usage,AdjustmentType=event,AdjustmentInputType=Amount,BillDate=2018-07-09,AdjustmentReason="Chargeback Event Adjustment",,SOAP Request:,AccountPOID="0.0.0.1 /account 324245253535",EventPOID="0.0.0.1 /event/activity/usage/payroll_per_employee 7378383763636373",AdjustmentAmount=1,AdjustmentPercentage=,Currency=GBP,Bill-ItemNo=23627727,1,AdjustmentDate=2018-07-14T04:00-07:00,IS_DEBIT_OR_CREDIT=CREDIT,TaxTreatment="Included Taxes in this adjustment",,SOAP Response:HttpStatus=200,,
```

if you see the above log, these are two events which are getting set in the same row but I am not able to extract in the table as two events.

Please suggest how can I extract it as two events.

Comment: What are the props.conf settings for that sourcetype?

Comment: Sir, I am just a user for the Splunk and I do not have admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

If you can identify a separator between the events, look at the `makemv` command.  It can split the event into a multivalue field.  Pipe it to `mvexpand` to create separate events to process.